# Why does my circuit breaker trip after the gas range turned on/off?

Tags: electrical, gas-burner

- Initially we turned the gas stove on. The ignition worked as usual.
- After some time, when we turned one of the burners off, the circuit breaker tripped. I reset the breaker.
- The next time when I turned one burner on, it tripped again.

Edited :
I live in Kentucky, USA. The stove is plugged in. it has burner ignition.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Usually a circuit breaker trips if a short is in the circuit, this could be dangerous and cause damage(fire) to the house.  Would leave breaker off and check or have the stove/circuit checked by an electrician.  In a few rare cases, the breaker itself is broken and needs replacement, can usually be checked by putting the stove on another same size  breaker.

Comment: A) Where in the world are you? B) Is the stove plugged in? (i.e. does it have electric burner ignition or an electric clock?)

Comment: Added details in the question's body. Thanks!

Comment: Is the stove plugged into a arc fault protected circuit?

Comment: So it worked once, but now every time you engage the igniter it throws the breaker?

Comment: @kris yes. @Duston; yes

Comment: Does the breaker have a test button? Is it GFCI, AFCI or both? Does it have a way to indicate trip reason?

Comment: An igniter will cause a trip on such a circuit.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes. both. No indication.

Comment: Same question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150586/gas-oven-tripping-gfci

Comment: @ kris an igniter MAY cause a trip of a AFCI or GFCI circuit, not necessarily will cause it.

Comment: @vickyP -- what make and model is your panel/breakers?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Square D, QO.